# <li> onclick with parameters

Tags: javascript, html

I am using an unordered list for a navigation bar on a webpage I am making for class. I am having some trouble getting the onClick method to fire. 

 My unordered list is below:

HTML:

```
<tr id="locationnavbar">
        <td>
            <ul id="locationlist">
                <li onClick="setMap('Pimms');">Pimms Good</li>
                <li onClick="setMap('Buzz');">The Buzz</li>
                <li onClick="setMap('Caffe');">Caffe Settimiano</li>
                <li onClick="setMap('Blue');">Blue Mug Coffee Bar</li>
                <li onClick="setMap('Pass');">Pascucci</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
  </tr>
```

Javascript:

```
function setMap(key) {
            alert(key);
 }
```

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? Thank you very much for you time. I am not using Jquery.

Comment: While I might have a lot to say if this was posted on code review, I [can't see any problem when I try the code](http://jsbin.com/xatibedu/1/edit)

Comment: That's so odd. I am running it in Chrome and it does not work for me. It could possibly be my CSS.

Comment: The same link works in Chrome for me too.

Comment: I commented out all my css relating to this section and it still does not work for me. I'm stumped.

Comment: Did you get any errors in console?

Comment: Is it possible that you have disabled `alert` notifications?

Comment: I'd suspect the problem has something to do with how you are including the JS. You need to create a reduced test case that still fails to work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no way to debug since I am programming in Notepad++.

Comment: Browsers come with JavaScript debuggers and error consoles.

Comment: i also face this problem in my code for chrome, that time i used `.click()` to get out of it

Comment: Try `function setMap(key){ console.log(key); }` and see whether it works.

Comment: @AHalbert, open your `Chrome` and press `Ctrl+Shift+I` than navigate to the `Console` tab and click on any of your `li` elements

Comment: Solved! I was able to debug it enough to see that an equality I was doing in a part of the code I did not post did not work properly. I wrongly assumed that the problem was in the listed code. Thank you very much for your time and effort!